How do I use a template from outside the Template namespace on MediaWiki?
I am testing a new Navbox template I want to use on a Fandom Wiki. I created this template under User:Stevoisiak/Template:MyNavbox so I could test it before making it a part of the site-wide Template: namespace.
Normally you can invoke templates by using {{TemplateName}}. However, invoking {{MyNavbox}} would pull from Template:MyNavbox when I want to pull my template from User:Stevoisiak/Template:MyNavbox.
How can I test a template that isn't in the Template namespace?

((User:Stevoisiak/Template:MyNavbox|…}}
